# Message.Hub Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015

Trabajo con windows Forms, Visual Studio 2015, Message.Hub

Tengo tiempo trabajando con este subscriptor de eventos sin problemas, ahora tengo la necesidad de subscribir un evento y se ejecute antes que el evento Load pero no esta sucesiendo eso, es al contrario el evento nunca se ejecuta.

Muestro el código que ocupo.

```
    private readonly ISaUsuario _saUsuario = CompositionRoot.Resolve<SaUsuario>();
    private readonly MessageHub _hub = MessageHub.Instance;

    public MDI()
    {
        _hub.Subscribe<BusquedaSelected>(OnUsuarioSelected);
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void OnUsuarioSelected(BusquedaSelected obj)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Valor))
        {
            var entity = _saUsuario.Single(x => x.User == obj.Valor);
            if (entity != null)
            {
                picFoto.Image = entity.Foto == null
                    ? ImageHelper.ObtenerImagenNoDisponible(AsignacionTablasType.Usuario)
                    : ImageHelper.ByteArrayToImage(entity.Foto);
                lblUsuario.Text = entity.Nombre;
            }
        }
    }

    private void MDI_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

Espero me puedan ayudar. Necesito que el evento `OnUsuarioSelected` se ejecute antes que el Load()

[Easy.MessageHub](https://github.com/NimaAra/Easy.MessageHub)

[Cleaner Pub-Sub using the Event Aggregator Pattern](http://www.nimaara.com/2016/02/14/cleaner-pub-sub-using-the-event-aggregator-pattern/)

Comment: Has probado a ejecutarlo tras iniciar los elementos del formulario, en el constructor del mismo?

Comment: Como dice Héctor, primero de todo va InitializeComponent(), sino los controles en el formulario no están inicializados.

Comment: Hector Lopez, Justamente en mi ejemplo muestro que creo el método en el constructor del formulario, debería de entrar al método al finalizar el InitializeComponent ¿a que te refieres?

Comment: @Luis también lo he probado después del InitializeComponet antes de postear mi pregunta igualmente no llama al método que esta creado. Lo que debería de pasar es que cuando salga del contructor entre al método y luego al evento Load.

Comment: Has intentado crear la subscripción en el evento load? O en el evento HandleCreated